# iOS: Default Back button Being Presented Over Custom Left Nav Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI7W4.png), once I push the view using: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];`

I have the code to create the left navigation button in viewWillAppear. 
Here's my code to create the left navigation button:

```
`UIButton *leftButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 25)];
            [leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"leftNavIconGray.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [leftButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
            [leftButton addTarget:self.navigationController.sideMenu action:@selector(toggleLeftSideMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            UIBarButtonItem *barBackItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBackItem;
            return;`
```

Notice, I do have the back button hidden in there. Because the left nav button is there, viewWillAppear is being called, but for some reason the default back button being hidden is not.

This only occurs when I push the view, not when I regularly load it.

Does anyone have any idea how to get that back button off of there?

Comment: do comment on `return;`

Comment: This does not work, and it is in the code for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think you if your work is not done

just hide the navigation bar

```
self.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

and on tap of leftButton (in toggleLeftSideMenu) just pop the view controller

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```